# What does the terms Sampling,Scanline Mean in Raster Graphics(Bresenham's Algorithm)

Tags: algorithm, graphics, raster, vector-graphics

Im a novice when it comes to computer graphics.Im trying to learn Bresenham's Scanline algorithm.

It says ***Pixels positions along a Line are determined by sampling at unit X intervals*** What exactly does this sampling mean,in layman's terms.

Then it says  ***Plot the pixel whose scan line value is closest to the line path***

What exactly is this scanline value? How is this computed ,again in layman's terms please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the wiki picture for  Bresenham algo.

Every horizontal row of pixels is scanline (term from old time raster printers and tube monitors). Sampling denotes using individual pixels' coordinates of every (scan)line. For example, if target graphic context has dimensions 1920x1080, there are 1920 pixels in scanline with X-coordinates 0..1919, and we do sampling (choose coloured pixels) for these integer coordinates. 
Note - line is contiguous math concept, but pixels are discrete.

Colored pixels are closer to the line than pixels with the same Y but from other scanlines

[image]

Comment: Please see https://books.google.co.in/books?id=WXzId7sBZiMC&pg=PA53&dq=bresenham+line+drawing+algorithm&hl=en&sa=X&ei=zCt1VcOGGsG1mAXH0YLwDg&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=bresenham%20line%20drawing%20algorithm&f=false What does it mean by -Pixels positions along a Line are determined by sampling at unit X intervals

Comment: Added more description

Comment: Thanks.okay.so sampling means to apply certain functions to a pixel/set of pixels to determine whether to plot it or not.

Comment: Not exactly so  - sampling is a process of choosing needed set of pixels to describe a line

Answer (score 2):

*Sampling:* Mathematically, a line is a continous (smooth) function. In raster graphics you have just a few pixels. So you need to represent (draw) such a line using a few pixels only. Sampling means to use the functions value at a few distinct points (instead of infinite many points).

*Scanline:* In this case the y value of the pixel. The term comes from the old CRT monitors where pictures are build from electron beams which followed a line pattern from left to right, one line after the next. The beam "scanned" these lines.

Comment: Please see https://books.google.co.in/books?id=WXzId7sBZiMC&pg=PA53&dq=bresenham+line+drawing+algorithm&hl=en&sa=X&ei=zCt1VcOGGsG1mAXH0YLwDg&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=bresenham%20line%20drawing%20algorithm&f=false What does it mean by -Pixels positions along a Line are determined by sampling at unit X intervals

Comment: It means: Instead of calculating the line _everywhere_ you calculate it _only_ for the center X-position of each pixel.

Comment: okay.so sampling means to apply certain functions to a pixel to determine whether to plot it or not?

Comment: sampling is a more general term: Calculate a function at certain points only. In your case: calculate it at pixel's x values only. So yes: calculate a function at an X-position to determine the Y-position and plot this pixel.